# mongodb check if point is in polygon

Tags: mongodb, polygon, point, mongodb-query

`mongo 2.6`

I have some amount of stored polygons. And I have a point. I what to know if this point fits any of stored polygons

document example

```
{ ..., "polygons" : [ [ 17.60083012593064, 78.18557739257812 ], [ 17.16834652544664, 78.19381713867188 ], [ 17.17490690610013, 78.739013671875 ], [ 17.613919673106714, 78.73489379882812 ] ], ... }
```

There is nearly the same question already [Mongodb : Check if a point is inside a stored polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866490/mongodb-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-stored-polygon).
But it is not working for me - this query has to give at least one result(the one in example) - but it does not.

```
db.areas.find( { polygons : { $geoIntersects : { $geometry : {type:"Point",coordinates:[17.3734, 78.4738]} } } } )
```

Actually if I chose a point on a border of any polygon - it does.

`$geoWithin` method has to do the work as `mondodb` documentation says.

but any of these queries do not work

```
db.areas.find( { polygons : { $geoWithin : { $geometry : {type:"Point",coordinates:[17.3734, 78.4738]} } } } ) - not supported with provided geometry

db.tradeareas.find( { polygons : { $geoWithin : { $geometry : {type:"Polygon",coordinates: inside_polygon} } } } ) - BadValue bad geo query
```

It seems I miss something but cant understand what and where.

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Are you using a 2d or a 2dsphere index?

Comment: I have posted a solution. Seems that order matters for point/polygon intersects queries.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It seems to be to do with the order. If you are using `$geoWithin` and you are trying to find points inside a polygon, the thing that is within is the field you are searching on. However, `$geoIntersects` works in either direction, so you can search for points inside polygons, or polygons containing points, eg:

```js
db.geom.insert({
  "polygons": {
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
      [ 17.60083012593064, 78.18557739257812],
      [ 17.16834652544664, 78.19381713867188],
      [ 17.17490690610013, 78.739013671875],
      [ 17.613919673106714, 78.73489379882812],
      [ 17.60083012593064, 78.18557739257812]
    ]]
  }
});

db.geom.find({
  polygons: {
    $geoIntersects: {
      $geometry: {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [17.3734, 78.4738]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Also, note that, you need to repeat the first point of the polygon at the end. If you remove the final pair, you will get a `$err`:

> Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad geo query" error.

It seems that MongoDB allows you to insert invalid geometries and only complains when you try and add a 2dsphere index or do an intersects/within/near query, which, I suppose is reasonable, as GeoJSON can be valid JSON without being a valid geometry.

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
I made such tests as you suggest - it does work correctly - just like in mongo documentation example. 
But I dont have polygons. I have just a point as parameter. To get a polygon I need to make a request to DB.  So with a million records - i need a 2 million requests to find all polygons that contains my point

Comment: @user3806072. I have updated my answer, it works as expected now, it will find all polygons that contain a point.

Comment: thank you very much - it does work. As you mentioned - The mistake was in incorrect GEOJSON structure of saved polygon.

Comment: @user3806072 I am having the same issue you were having. I do think it's the GEOJSON structure of the saved polygon. What did you change the structure to? What does your schema look like? Thanks much!

Comment: What do you mean  by "It seems to be to do with the order"?

Comment: Would it be possible to achieve the same thing if we have a multiple of polygons and points within our database? Could we have point-in-polygon analysis in MongoDB implicity?

Comment: @banbar. Sorry, I don't really work with MongoDB any more. I am sure you can achieve that, but I think you might want to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [John Powell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24605748/942855) here is C# driver version of the same query.

```
 var geometry = new BsonDocument
                            {
                                     { "type", "Point" },
                                     { "coordinates",
                                        new BsonArray(new double[]{ Longitude,
                                        Latitude} ) }
                            };
                    var geometryOperator = new BsonDocument { { "$geometry", geometry } };
                    var geoIntersectsOperator = new BsonDocument { { "$geoIntersects", geometryOperator } };

                    var findField = new BsonDocument { { "geometry", geoIntersectsOperator } };


                    var results = MyCollection.Find(findField).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java it Can be done this way

```java
@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOpertions;
    
public void pointIntersect(GeoJsonPoint gp){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("geometry").intersects(gp));
    List<ResultDtoType> result = mongoOpertions.find(query, ResultDtoType.class);
    //perform any action with result 
}
```